# Use ASP.NET or Sharepoint

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

We have a project about to be sized for a US Govt agency.  The data is contained in an Oracle database and contains about 1 1/2 million rows, all documents.  There is the need to create records that link these documents to certain records.  It is a many-to-many scenario.  Because it is a govt agency, each of these docs and records must contain a clearance designation.  Also, with that, there must be groups that can view or edit or not even see these particular coded documents.

I know this can be done with an ASP.NET approach in various pages and controlled with C# code behind and JavaScript and/or jQuery, but, my question is, would this be better suited for a Sharepoint project?

Comment: If the idea is to maintain all the docs in Oracle and SharePoint isn't currently used for other things already, I don't think it would be beneficial to deploy SharePoint. Adding SharePoint is no trivial task just in itself and by the way you are describing the project, it seems to me that it would add a lot of additional work and it would be hard to justify the licensing cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from someone who specializes in SharePoint, I'm on the fence for your specific requirements. It will excel at many things you mentioned, but the ones that concern me are the many-to-many relationships you mentioned as well as the document load.

SharePoint is *not* good at relational data. Lookup columns don't really count, and many times you'll end up implementing some very dirty things to make SharePoint mimic a relational DB.

1.5 million documents means you'll need to very carefully plan how these are stored in SharePoint. There are software boundaries you will quickly breach if you simply dumped these all into a single site across a few document libraries. That's not to say it's unsupported - there are just best practices on how to store/consume that many documents without causing performance degradation. With that number of documents, if the requirement is for them to exist under a single site you'll then probably want to start looking into implementing remote blob storage, which is additional logistics/licensing.

SharePoint *is* very good at versioning, document locking, information management policies, workflow (with some TLC,) collaboration, searching, classifying, etc.

Frankly, this problem is too complex to give a definitive answer to on this site. It's definitely "doable" in SharePoint, and many of the out of box functions of SharePoint are right up your alley for how the system is currently used. Some of your other requirements, however, will be far less painful to implement if you have the type of fine-grained control granted by doing so in a custom webapp.

You need to engage a vendor that specializes in both practices (asp.net and SharePoint) and have them thoroughly evaluate both options with you. A gap analysis of your requirements vs current state and the two options would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. There's many other variables at work here. Is there an AD environment? Is that environment already suited for the security scheme you describe?

Do you have to stay on Oracle?

What kind of machinations need to happen to the documents? Are these retrieve/read type operations or are you also editing? Versioning? Allow users to create their own folder structures?

Given the Oracle back-end you will most likely be better off with the home-grown C# approach. But again, it depends on the answers to the above.

Comment: I neglected to mention that the whole process was written with Oracle forms some time ago, that's why the DB.  Docs are being grouped, versioned, edited, locked, and printed.